# Can only access gvfs-mount in nautilus

Tags: mount, nautilus, samba, gvfs, fuse

I am trying to mount a Windows network drive using `gvfs-mount`,

`gvfs-mount smb://<server_name>/<share_name>/<folder_name>`

The folder seems to be mounted correctly, as I can browse it in nautilus. However, when trying to `ls` the corresponding FUSE mount at

`/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=<server_name>,share=<share_name>`,

I am prompted with `ls: reading directory .: Permission denied`. The folder (`/run/user/...`) is owned by me. I am a member of the `fuse` group. Other relevant information may be:

1. I had permission issues when mounting the same share using `mount.cifs`, but I was assuming that `gvfsd-fuse`/nautilus uses a completely different backend?
2. I only have permissions to access a certain folder (`<folder_name>`) on the share

So how can I make the fuse mount point work?